# Get multiple meta content values using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meta-tags

What is the most efficient way to grab multiple meta tag values using jQuery?  I'm storing some values in meta tags that I want to read in via jQuery and either pass along to ajax calls or make changes to the UI based on.  The code base I'm working on currently has this...

```
params: {
    ad_hash:                $('meta[property=ad_hash]').attr('content'),
    ad_id:                  $('meta[property=ad_id]').attr('content'),
    ad_advertiser_id:       $('meta[property=ad_advertiser_id]').attr('content'),
    ad_subcategory_id:      $('meta[property=ad_subcategory_id]').attr('content'),
    ad_est_firstoccur:      $('meta[property=ad_est_firstoccur]').attr('content'),
    ad_est_lastoccur:       $('meta[property=ad_est_lastoccur]').attr('content'),
    ad_firstoccur:          $('meta[property=ad_firstoccur]').attr('content'),
    ad_lastoccur:           $('meta[property=ad_lastoccur]').attr('content'),
    ad_time:                $('meta[property=ad_time]').attr('content'),
    ad_timestamp:           $('meta[property=ad_timestamp]').attr('content'),
    ad_rating:              $('meta[property=ad_rating]').attr('content'),
    hostname:               $('meta[property=hostname]').attr('content'),
    user_clientip:          $('meta[property=user_clientip]').attr('content'),
    user_searchterm:        $('meta[property=user_searchterm]').attr('content'),
    user_voted:             $('meta[property=user_voted]').attr('content'),
    trans_recentlyaired:    $('meta[property=trans_recentlyaired]').attr('content'),
    trans_lastaired:        $('meta[property=trans_lastaired]').attr('content'),
    trans_on:               $('meta[property=trans_on]').attr('content'),
    trans_during:           $('meta[property=trans_during]').attr('content'),
    trans_tobeaired:        $('meta[property=trans_tobeaired]').attr('content')
},
```

Is there a more efficient way to grab multiple meta tag values than making multiple trips to the dom? Here are some alternate solutions I've considered...

- I could limit the scope by adding head: $('meta[property=ad_hash]', 'head').attr('content')
- I could store all the values in a single JSON string, but I ran into some problems reading it in from a meta tag.
- Is there a way to use $('meta') to store the matches against a variable and then access the individual tags within it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a JSON string would be more efficient size-wise, but essentially you're just parsing XML data. You could loop through the `meta` tags, in order to reduce how often you select from the DOM, and to make your code more dynamic:

```
var params = {};
$('head meta[property][content]').each(function() {
    params[$(this).attr('property')] = $(this).attr('content');
});
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to share the HTML you're trying to parse (dummy data is fine)? That way I can test it to see what's wrong.

Comment: Looks like it fails on the this.property...
http://jsbin.com/siguhutole/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @AdamYoungers It looks like `this.property` doesn't stay synchronized with the attribute on `meta` tags. Now using `attr` to make sure it gets the attribute.

Comment: @AdamYoungers You may want to use `name` instead of `property` for your `meta` tags. That way you'll be using standardized attribute names.